# how to keep background layout focused when touching sliding menu in android?

Tags: android, sliding

as android default ,when you touch the sliding menu,it gets focused from back ground layout but i want to keep the background focused.
for example like viber app when you touch the setting,it pushes the background away but both of them (sliding menu and background layout ) are focused.
this is my xml for layouts:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

  <FrameLayout

    <RelativeLayout

      <GridView

      </GridView>
    </RelativeLayout>

  </FrameLayout>

  <ListView

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Do you mean the shadow that gets applied on the main content?

Comment: yes, i don't want my main content get shadow. how to disable this shadow?

Comment: I use https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu in my app for Navigation menu where in we can shadow. Not sure about DrawerLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the answer. you should put this code in your main activity

```
  mDrawerLayout.SetScrimColor(Android.Resource.Color.Transparent);
```